# Contact Name field issue in the Quote object

Tags: process-builder

In the Quote object , we have a standard field " Contact Name" which is a look up to the Contact object.

I want that, while creating a new quote, the "Account Name" should automatically autopupulate in the Contact Name field. The account name choosen is " personal account" so it should not be an issue. I tried the workflow and process builder but not able to work it out.
In Quote object , the contact name field is not showing in the process builder, so i had taken the Contact ID, which should have been worked, But no success. can anyone plz suggest how to do this ?

Below is my screenshot , what i did for the process builder, ( selected the " Quote" object initially)

In the criteria,

[image]

In the immediate action,

[image]

and activated. I assume it should work but not working.

Comment: instead of Id use, `firstname` or `LastName`

Comment: It will not let you populate an Id field with the Id of a different object type, if you are using Person Accounts the Account Id is not the same as the contact id, as in fact each person account actually has 2 id fields - Account Id and Contact Id, however it is not recommended to use the contact id from the person account as it can produce some odd behaviours.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the clarification. Thanks Tushar i will try with the names.